# PHP pthreads object variable uninitialized

Tags: php, c++, pthreads

I have just installed pthreads for PHP. However when I created an object of the thread class. The object member variables are uninitialized when I created the objec. I don't know why, her is my code

I created a new object as follows:

```
  $request = new CopyFile('123','123','123','123','123');
```

But the variables of $request are all uninitialized. I can step into the constructor of CopyFile. And I found that the constructor did receive parameter values and values is passed to $this.

The Thread Class:

```
class CopyFile extends Thread {
public $file;
public $extension;
public $location;
public $type;

public function __construct($file,$extension,$location,$type,$id){
    $this->$file = $file;
    $this->$extension = $extension;
    $this->$location = $location;
    $this->$type = $type;
    $this->$id = $id;       
}

public function run(){

    $key = $this.$location . '/' . $this.$id . '.' . $this.$extension;      

    log::info($result);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor is not correct it should be as below.
To assign a value or access member variables you need the following syntax

```
$this->var_name = 'some_val' ; // no $ sign before the variable name


public function __construct($file,$extension,$location,$type,$id){
    $this->file = $file;
    $this->extension = $extension;
    $this->location = $location;
    $this->type = $type;
    $this->id = $id;       
}
```

Similarly

```
$key = $this.$location . '/' . $this.$id . '.' . $this.$extension;
```

Should be

```
$key = $this->location . '/' . $this->id . '.' . $this->extension;
```

You may also need to have a variable id something as

```
public $id ;
```

Comment: Thanks so much Abhik. I have spent many hours on it. You have solved my problems in just a minute. I need to learn more about object oriented syntax.

Comment: You are most welcome and yes check the PHP manual it has nice examples to start with.